# Is Master Roshi really bald?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

This question arose when I was watching Krillin vs Jackie Chun who is Master Roshi. When Yamcha pulls the hair thinking it is a wig, but it won't come off, then he thinks it is real hair and asks that then the bald one should be a wig? Please, could anyone explain?

Comment: Welcome to SE! You might want to go to the site's help page. If an answer is satisfying, please accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Master Roshi is really bald. He mentions it himself in Chapter 25:

[image]

In the first tournament, he used a special glue to attach his hair. He mentions it when revealing his identity to Nam, who was just defeated by Goku (Chapter 46):[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed explanation in the second movie of Dragon Ball "the sleeping princess". minute 6:40. 
Krillin arrives. Goku tells him he's bold. Krillin says all great Martial Artists shave, just like Master Roshi. Master Roshi says he's simply bald, nothing else.

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote?

Comment: For people that don't understand it I said exactly what solalito wrote in the first 2 images (it's the same scene, just check it) and I said it first (he added that 10 hours after my post). I don't think a -1 reflects how good the answer is.

Comment: I think it's probably since Solalito's answer is from the manga and that specific scene takes place in the anime too. I'm also not certain, but I believe the movies are not considered canon.

Comment: @trafalgarlaw +1, because I dont think your answer deserved to be negative. Your answer is good, but are you referring from the anime or the movie? As WMios stated, the movies are non-canon. Also, it's always better appreciated when one cites the source itself (in this case the manga) or at least the wikia page. For your case, I don't think anyone is going to take the trouble going to a specific minute of an old Dragon Ball movie just to check if you got your facts right.